# table not found one to many relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

my database

```
Schema::create('request_topics', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('status')->nullable()->default('Pending');
        $table->integer('request_category_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('request_category_id')->references('id')->on('request_categories')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and

```
Schema::create('request_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title')->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('description');
        $table->boolean('pin')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

when i fetch like `{{ count($requestcategory->requesttopics) }}` its working fine but when i fetch

```
$requesttopics = RequestTopic::whereHas('requestcategories', function ($query) use($slug){
            $query->where('slug', $slug);
        })->paginate('20');
```

getting error column not found

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'request_topics.requestcategories_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `request_topics`

something went wrong with my code or i am doing something wrong
help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have `requestcategories` relation in your model? If yes then you should check second and third parameters (local and foreign keys)

```
public function requestcategories(){

  return $this->belongsTo('App\RequestCategory', 'request_category_id', 'id');

}
```

Comment: "protected $fillable = [
        'description', 'title', 'slug'
    ];

    public function requesttopics(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\RequestTopic');
        
    }"

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jtq1my RequestTopic Table
http://prntscr.com/jtq1vd RequestCategory Table

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html

You should specify parameters correctly, so that your related table able to connect to your local table, you should specify second and third parmaeters as local and foreign keys for example $this->hasMany('App\RequestTopic', 'request_category_id', 'id');

Comment: i did like this http://prntscr.com/jtq85u but still getting same error :(

Comment: thanks i added to this return $this->belongsTo('App\RequestCategory', 'request_category_id', 'id'); and its working fine